# How to scroll horizontally an absolute element to where I want?

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm sorry if the question doesn't sound right, I had no idea how to describe my problem clearer.

I have a website (in development): http://baronettes.tapagecommunication.com
As you can see, when scrolling or selecting an item on the menu, the window scrolls but the menu stays at the same absolute position. The little "dent" in the logo, must be centered with the circle on the left of each sections.
It works well for all sections, but not for the last one, since I don't know the width of the window. If you resize your window horizontally, you're going to see what I'm talking about.

I'm trying to find a solution to this problem but have 0 idea right now.

It might be worth noting that I'm using the localScroll plugin for the sliding.

So, if anybody has some kind of beginning of an idea, let me know :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have 2 sets of circles, "position: fixed" and "position: relative". Hide all of the fixed circles until their position is scrolled to, and then dynamically hide the relative ones and unhide the fixed ones to make it look like they "snap" in place.

Or you can create a zero height block level element outside your super-wide container div, and use javascript to find its width to estimate the width of the screen (and refresh when resized). (note that unless you set everything up manually, eg. margins, padding, etc. the number will be slightly different between browsers)

Comment: I liked that idea so I marked it as the answer. I actually went a different way. I use the animate() function from jquery to move the menu to the right place when the user is done scrolling. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "fake" section of the appropriate size on the far right, but don't provide a link for this section.

Does this make sense?

Comment: It does make sense, but I will be left with a long "unused" part of the website. And it doesn't really solve the problem depending on the width of the window (not sure if I'm clear on this)